# Pruebas Unitarias y de Cobertura Java Reactive Flux y Mono

Tags: java, unittest, mono, spring-webflux, cobertura

Tengan un saludo cordial, de antemano gracias por las ayuda que me puedan brindar, tengo un servicio en java que utiliza Flux y Mono y me han asignado las pruebas de cobertura, pero no logro avanzar ya que se queda en la linea de emitter, les copio el codigo}

FUNCION DEL SERVICIO

```
public Mono<ClaseRetorno> respuesta(String a, String b, String c, String d) {       
    AtomicInteger lote = new AtomicInteger();
    StringBuilder NombreDatos = new StringBuilder();        
    return Flux.create(
        emitter -> {
            List<Lista> listado = listadoDao.buscarListadoZC(a, b, c, d);              
            int cs = ConsC.CERO;
            String v = "";             
            if (!Util.validNullOrEmpty(listado)) {
                if (cs == ConsC.CERO) {
                    v = listado.get(cs).getNames();
                    if (Util.validString(v)) {
                        NombreDatos.append(v);
                    }
                    cs++;
                }
                lote.set(listado.get(ConsC.CERO).getNumLoteProc());

                listado.stream().forEach(c -> {
                    emitter.next(c);
                });
            }
            emitter.complete();
        })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(ejecutarConsultaBD)).map(c -> {
        return (Lista) c;
    })
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(ejecutarTareaSimple))
    .map(JsonUtils::getRootNode).flatMap(
        tr -> {
            return joltRequestConversorReactor.translate(tr, ConsC.JJJJ_CLLL_ZZZ);
        })
    .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(ejecutarTareaSimple)).sequential().collectList()
    .map(
        r -> {
            ClaseRetorno xxx = new ClaseRetorno();              
            ncz.setMensaje_ejecucion(messageSource.getMessage(Constantes.CODEBASEEXITO + CodeResponse.OBTENER_EXITO.getCode() + Constantes.CODE_MESSAGE, null, l));
            ncz.setNumLoteProceso(lote.get());                              
            String Valor = "null".equals(NombreDatos.toString()) ? "" : NombreDatos.toString();                           
            ncz.setValor(Valor);
            ncz.setDatos(r);                           
            return xxx;
        }
    );
}
```

Por cuestionos de seguridad eh cambiado nombre de variables y todo eso, pero el punto es que cuando trato d realizar pruebas de cobertura a esa función nunca avanza mas de la linea que dice emitter, si alguien tuviera un ejemplo de como poder realizar dichas pruebas se lo agradecería.

Solo pude realizar estos test:

```
    Flux<Cliente> source = Flux.fromIterable(listado);
Mono<ClaseRetorno> strMono = Mono.just(claseRetorno);
//changeNotifyServiceImpl.changezone(a,b, c, d)
// Mockito.when(listadoDao.buscarListadoZC(a,b, c, d)).thenReturn(listado);
StepVerifier.create(strMono)
    .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: Por favor, haz clic en [edit] y añade los tests que has elaborado para poder ayudarte con ellos.